# Copy Range Sheet1 Paste in Active Cell Sheet 2

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

1. Sheet1: User clicks a button that runs VBA.
2. Sheet2: VBA selects the first non-blank cell on column D

   Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
3. Sheet1: VBA copies a range of values

   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:AJ11").Copy
4. Sheet2: VBA pastes the copied range into the active cell selected previously.

**This part where I try pasting into the active cell is not working:**

```
Worksheets("Results").ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code could use some refining, but to keep your code and make it work I would change the order of commands to this and see if that works for you.

1. Sheet1: User clicks a button that runs VBA.
2. Sheet1: VBA copies a range of values
3. Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:AJ11").Copy

then to sheet 2

1. Sheet2: VBA selects the first non-blank cell on column D
2. Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select *(or just paste instead of select)*
3. Sheet2: VBA pastes the copied range into the active cell selected previously.

or just skip the line that is bothering you and instead use:

```
Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).pastespecial xlpastevalues
```

(adjust as you need, this is for values)

Or use something like this:

```
Sub Copy()

Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Results As Worksheet

    Set Results = Sheets("Results")
    LastRow = Results.Cells(Results.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).row

    Range("E2:AJ11").Copy
    Results.Range("D" & LastRow + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Karl! My main problem is that the user doesn't want to go to Sheet2. There's another VBA that user runs on Sheet1, and every time they run it, the values that needs to be copied are getting updated. I was hoping to make it work so that the user does everything on Sheet1 without going back and forth between sheets...

Comment: Ok, I added some other code here that should be easy to read. BR.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
Dim i as Integer
i = 1

Do while cells(i,4) <> ""
    Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:AJ11").Copy
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: Thanks, Jenna! :) I'm getting an error, but that's ok, the previous response worked for me. Hope you have a great night!

Comment: Remove the not in Do While. Thanks.